# Using jQuery to change attributes?

Tags: jquery, html

I have a table that in each row there is a checkbox and at the bottom of the table there is a input box that we can enter color name in it (example : fff). and when we click on submit change color of all 'tr' that checked check boxes to the color that we entered in inputbox

Comment: Please post an example of you HTML so we can see exactly what you are talking about.

Comment: this is a question that my teacher asked me and i should answer it

Comment: For such questions in future, be sure to tag it as [homework](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/homework)

Answer (score 2):

It would be easier if we could see your html.

```
$('form').submit(function() {
    var sColor = '#' + $('input[type="text"]').val();
    $('input:checked').closest('tr').css('background-color', sColor);
    return false;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You mean like this?

http://jsfiddle.net/GZaqD/

```
$("#btn").click(function(){
    $("input:checked").parents("tr").css({background:"#" + $("#color").val()});
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I created a simple example of what I think you want to do. Hopefully it should get you started. Check it out on jsfiddel, http://jsfiddle.net/YGWKA/